# Navbar not aligning to element below it, why?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

[Hosting Folder](https://128adea15bfc1bafb9f65665da2a849fe09dc13a.googledrive.com/host/0B71AnQstJeptYUpjOW9ZLXpTWmc)

If you click the link then click on "all.html", you should see an unfinished navbar with the two items "Sample" and "Text". You should also see the fact that the blue padding cuts into the white background below it.

I've tried playing with the margins and padding of all the elements of and inside the `#topnav` div to no avail. I've tried changing `display`, `float`, and `text-align`, but that creates more problems if it even solves the current problem. I've tried multiple tutorials and have rewritten both the html and css for this navbar twice at this point, yet I keep getting stuck on this one issue: The blue part of the navbar cuts into the white. The navbar should look as it does [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B71AnQstJeptVzdXZE5hN2JyVkU).

Could anyone tell me why the blue is cutting into the white, even with appropriate margin and padding widths? Thank you! (Note that the page is using Bootstrap v3.3.1)

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="#">Sample</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topnav{
    display: inline;
}
#topnav *{
    display:inherit;
}
#topnav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
    background-color: rgb(0,93,164);
    padding: 15px;
}
#topnav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
#topnav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#topnav a:hover{
    background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `ul` element has `display: inline`. Change it to `inline-block` or `block`:

```
#topnav ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a lot of headache

Answer (score 0):

```
#topnav ul {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```